# How to print/get specific lines in an Html file in python 3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I wanted to print a specific line from my HTML file. The specific line being the one enclosed as a header. My test.html file is posted at the bottom for reference

```
import codecs
import re
f = codecs.open("test.html", 'r')
f.read()
paragraphs = re.findall(r'<html>(.*?)</html>',str(f))
print(paragraphs)
f.close()
```

test.html looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Example
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
import codecs
import re
g = codecs.open("test.html", 'r')
f = g.read()
start = f.find("<head>")
start = start + 7
end =  f.find("</head>")
end = end - 1
paragraphs = f[start:end]
print(paragraphs)
g.close()
```

this prints

```
<title>
Example
</title>
```

`.find()` returns the starting index of the substring inside the string you searched, then we use those indexes (after applying some simple math) to access the substring by slicing the string with `[:]`.